# Xamarin.forms - Trouble behaviour between ListView & keyboard

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, keyboard

I'm workin' on an Xamarin.forms app chat and I'm havin' some troubles with the `listView`. The first one is that when I'm ready to type some message, the keyboard overlapps the main chat. The second one occurs when I hide the keyboard and the `listView` doesn't scroll all the away down. Is there some convention solution to this type of problems? Here's the video and the respective code:

[VIDEO](https://files.fm/f/6tv9ujkr)

**My xaml Page:**

```
  <StackLayout>


        <ListView 
                    x:Name="MessagesListView" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Pedidos}" 
                    HasUnevenRows="True"  SeparatorVisibility="None"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackGroundColor}"/>


        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource white}" Grid.Row="1">

            <local1:CustomEntry 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  

                Placeholder="{translator:Translate Mensagem}"  
                Keyboard="Chat"  Margin="8,0,0,0" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource PlaceHolderText}" TextColor="{StaticResource texto}"  FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Pedido.Message}" x:Name="Message"/>
            <Image Source="send.png" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" Margin="8,8,8,8" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                           Command="{Binding EnviarPedidoCommand}"
                           Tapped="Button_Clicked"
                            />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Backend page:

```
 public ChatPage(Classes.ClassConversation.ResultadoConversation conversation, Classes.ClassUser.Result user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetResult = conversation;
        ConnectionsStrings.GlobalVar.email = user.rowKey;
        GetUser = user;

        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

        _viewModel = new ViewModels.ConnectionHub(conversation, user);

    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();
        GetHistoryOfConversation(GetResult.rowKey, ConnectionsStrings.GlobalVar.Token, GetUser);

        BindingContext = _viewModel;

        await _viewModel.Connect();
    }

    protected override async void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        await _viewModel.Disconnect();
    }

    //Limpa o campo mensagem quando envia mensagem
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message.Text = "";     
    }

    //Função que recebe o historico de mensagens daquela conversa
    async void GetHistoryOfConversation(string conversationId, string token, Classes.ClassUser.Result user)
    {
        try
        {
            Classes.ClasMessage messages = await Servicos.Servicos.GetHistoryOfConversation(conversationId, token, user, GetResult);
            _viewModel.Pedidos = new ObservableRangeCollection<Classes.SendMessage>(messages.result);

            var target = _viewModel.Pedidos[_viewModel.Pedidos.Count - 1];
            MessagesListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, false);

            var result = await Servicos.Servicos.ReadConversation(conversationId, GetResult);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(Languages.AppResources.Notifications, Languages.AppResources.ErrorOccurred, "Ok");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373761/how-to-set-listview-to-start-showing-the-last-item-instead-in-xamarin-forms.

You have to scroll the ListView to the last item.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. It works on appearing but when I insert registration by the viewmodel it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try to rotate Listview and and add item in top of list

Answer (score 1):

> The first one is that when I'm ready to type some message, the
>   keyboard overlapps the main chat.

For the first question, you should detect the keyboard up/down and move up/down the listView.

In **Android**, you can use [Soft Keyboard Input Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode)

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</Application>
```

In **iOS** , you need to write a custom renderer to detect the event.

You can check the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467135/xamarin-form-move-up-view-when-keyboard-appear) and read [this blog](https://xamgirl.com/adjusting-elements-when-keyboard-shows-in-xamarin-forms/) for solutions.

> The second one occurs when I hide the keyboard and the listView
>   doesn't scroll all the away down.

You should scroll the listView in the `EnviarPedidoCommand` after you insert that message to the itemSource of listView.

Comment: hello, I'm on android already using "resize" the problem is that the content of the listview when the keyboard is open, the content of the listview does not show the last message. To see this message, you need to scroll. 


If I use the "pan" the problem from above does not occur but the toolbar disappears and the listview scroll does not show all the data.

Comment: What's your problem on iOS?

Comment: On ios it's working properly. When the keyboard is open, the last item in the listview is displayed.

Comment: Did you scroll the listView to last element in the EnviarPedidoCommand after you send the message? You should use "Resize".

Comment: .My problem with SendRequestCommand is that this command is in the viewmodel. and then I can't access the list scroll.

Im using resize. you can see in my code.

Comment: How about use a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to notify listView to scroll?